# How to replace strings in pandas column that are in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have scrolled through the posts on this question and was unable to find an answer to my situation. I have a pandas dataframe with a list of company names, some of which are represented as their domain name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['amazon.us', 'pepsi', 'YOUTUBE.COM', 'apple.inc'], columns=['firm'])
```

I want to remove the domain extension from all the strings. The extensions are given in a list:

```
web_domains = ['.com', '.us']
```

The ollowing attepmt did not yield any results:

```
df['firm'].str.lower().replace(web_domains, '')
```

Can someone please help me out, and possibly also explain why my solution does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `regex=True` for [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) since it matches exact string under `regex=False`.

For example `a` will only be replaced when target is `a` not `ab` nor `bab`

```py
web_domains = ['\.com', '\.us'] # escape `.` for regex=True

df['removed'] = df['firm'].str.lower().replace(web_domains, '', regex=True)
```

```
print(df)

          firm    removed
0    amazon.us     amazon
1        pepsi      pepsi
2  YOUTUBE.COM    youtube
3    apple.inc  apple.inc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

web_domains = ['.com', '.us']
df = pd.DataFrame(['amazon.us', 'pepsi', 'YOUTUBE.COM', 'apple.inc'], columns=['firm'])

regex_pattern = f"({ '|'.join(re.escape(wb) for wb in web_domains)})$"
res = df["firm"].str.replace(regex_pattern, "", regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0       amazon
1        pepsi
2      YOUTUBE
3    apple.inc
Name: firm, dtype: object
```

The variable `regex_pattern` points to the string:

```
(\.com|\.us)$
```

it will match either `.com` or `.us` at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Form a regex alternation from the domain endings, then use `str.replace` to remove them:

```py
web_domains = ['com', 'us']
regex = r'\.(?:' + r'|'.join(web_domains) + r')$'
df["firm"] = df["firm"].str.replace(regex, '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

> explain why my solution does not work?

[`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) first argument should be

> str or compiled regex

you have shoved list here, which is not allowed.